# Google maps info window give same result on different markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Have following problem, the infowindow, gives the same result on different markers.
When I debug outside **geocoder.geocode** function it shows the right info, but inside always the same (first one). the suppid part is when i debug the i variable inside it shows the correct value.

```
var optionMap = {
            zoom: 16,
            MapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), optionMap);

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/gm_pin.png',
        new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

        for(var i = 0; i < arrAddress.length; i++) {

            var address = arrAddress[i];

            var html_title = "<div class='info'><h4>" + address + "</h4></div>";

            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function (results, status) {

                 if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {


                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: icon,
                        html: html_title, 
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });

                    var contentString = '';

                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString

                        });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {  
                        infoWindow.setContent(this.html);
                        infoWindow.open(map, this);
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {  
                        infoWindow.close(map, this);
                    });

                    latlngbounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);

                    if(i == arrAddress.length) {
                        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
                    }

                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `Geocoder.geocode(request, callback)` [is asynchronous](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html#GeocodingRequests). When the server responds the callback function is called. Usually by this time, the for loop has already finished. This can have exactly the results that you describe, e.g. each marker has the same content, because the marker is created in the callback, which happens after the loop is finished, and thus it will use the last value that was in `html_title`.

The way to fix this is by creating a closure inside the loop, that will 'capture' the variable `html_title` inside the loop. This way, the callback will use the correct value of `html_title`.

A typical explicit closure in JavaScript looks like this:

```
// Wrap a function in () and immediately call it with another ()
// Pass in the arguments in the second () 
// This causes them to be 'captured' inside the function
(function(args) { /* Do something with args */ })("Hello", 42);
```

In your code, the closure will need to capture an address during the loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrAddress.length; i++) {
  var address = arrAddress[i];
  var html_title = "<div class='info'><h4>" + address + "</h4></div>";

  (function(address, title) {
    // Inside the closure, we can use address and html_title
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address /* captured */}, function (results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          html: title, /* captured */ 
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });

        var contentString = '';
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });

        // ...
      }
    });
  })(address, html_title); // <- Call function, pass the vars to be captured 
}
```

Comment: Thanx this is working, one question can I put it also in a seperate function?

Comment: Technically it is a separate function already. So yes, you can move that to a named function and call that function from inside the loop.